# doing an awk followed by a head command + bash

Tags: bash, awk, head

This gives me the duplicates and the number of times it is repeated

```
$ awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 2
      4 12345
      3 56789
```

What I then want to do is add the first column (3+4). I can do this if i write the output above to a file `test`. I can do this as follows:

```
$ awk -F" " '{print $1}' test
4
3
$ awk -F" " '{print $1}' test | paste -sd+
4+3
$ awk -F" " '{print $1}' test | paste -sd+ | bc
7
```

But I want to be able to do this in 1 line, and ideally don't want to write to a file, would like to understand why the following does not work

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 2 | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

My 2nd awk seems to not like the input.

Can anyone advise how I do this, and what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT1** - file.csv looks like:

```
"Date","Number"
"2015-11-01","12345"
"2015-11-01","12345"
"2015-11-01","12345"
"2015-11-01","12345"
"2015-11-01","56789"
"2015-11-01","56789"
"2015-11-01","56789"
```

Comment: Can you provide the file.csv? Using a fake file.csv here your second command (one-liner) works fine for me.

Comment: @Onilton have added what file.csv looks like

Comment: Your one-liner command still works fine here for me =/. What OS are you using?

Comment: What is the output of just `awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 2 | awk -F" " '{print $1}'` ?

Comment: `4
3
` using windows 7

Comment: For me it prints `4\n3` (\n is newline, but I can't type newline in comments ^^) (I'm using ubuntu linux) I think there is something wrong with your awk (or with window's awk)

Comment: ye seems to be working for me now...confused....ooh well!!

Comment: Anyway, you could workaround this issue by replacing spaces with newline:

`awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 2 | awk -F" " '{print $1}' |  tr ' ' '\n' | paste -sd+ | bc`

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
... | sort -nr | awk 'NR<=2{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
```

you can pick the first two rows and summation in awk as well.

Comment: You might as well just replace the entire thing with awk since you can. =)

Comment: tks @karakfa, I was just using head for testing a small portion of data, but good to know i can use `NR<=2` just to do it on the first 2 rows.